# partial fraction problem

Tags: partial-fractions

I have thought for a long time but general method is not working  :

$$\frac{s^2+2}{(s+2)^2(s^2+2s+2)^2}$$

Thanks for all help.

Comment: You miss one $)$ in the expression.

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{s^2+2}{(s+2)^2(s^2+2s+2)^2} = \frac{As+B}{(s+2)^2}+ \frac{Cs^3+Ds^2+Es+F}{(s^2+2s+2)^2}$$

Comment: Thanks for the edit, vecino !